# Convert epoch times in text file

Tags: powershell, time, epoch

I'm trying to convert epoch time for several timestamps in a text file, and I have the code below. I know the replace line is wrong, but I don't know how to use a foreach-object to complete this task.

```
Function Convert-FromUnixdate ($UnixDate) {
   ,[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').`
   AddmilliSeconds($UnixDate))
}

$convert = Get-Content -Path C:\test\test.txt
$convert -Replace "[0-9]{13}", 'Convert-FromUnixdate($_)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a "normal" regular expression replacement the code you have would work. The `-replace` operator can be used on an array of strings (which is what `Get-Content` returns).

However, since you want to use a function in a replacement you cannot use that operator, regardless of whether you apply it to an array or in a loop to each array element. Instead you need to define the regular expression as a `[regex]` object and use its `Replace()` method to call a callback function/scriptblock on the array elements.

```
function Convert-FromUnixDate($UnixDate) {
  [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([DateTime]'1/1/1970').AddMilliseconds($UnixDate))
}

$re = [regex]'\d{13}'
$callback = { Convert-FromUnixDate($args[0].Value) }

Get-Content -Path 'C:\test\test.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $re.Replace($_, $callback)
}
```

Comment: the timestamps don't convert due to a mismatch in type.

Comment: Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "1432302520693", for "AddMilliseconds" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert the "1432302520693" value of type 
"System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match" to type "System.Double"."
At line:2 char:3
+   [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([DateTime]'1/1/1970').AddmilliSeconds ...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

Comment: @SO03112 My bad. You must pass the *value* of the regex match to `Convert-FromUnixDate`, not the match itself. See updated answer.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I understand most of it except the callback line. I'm going to try to figure that out now.

Comment: @SO03112 Technically it's a [scriptblock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx), which is more or less PowerShell's version of [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

Answer (score 0):

Get-Content returns an array of strings, one for each line in the file.

So you could do

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path C:\test\test.txt))
{
    $line -Replace "[0-9]{13}", 'Convert-FromUnixdate($line)'
}
```

Or with a more minimalistic variant as

```
Get-Content -Path C:\test\test.txt | % {$_ -Replace "[0-9]{13}", 'Convert-FromUnixdate($_)'}
```

Still the -replace line does not work, as you stated yourself.